# Recommended NetBeans UML plugins

Tags: netbeans, plugins, uml

It appears that the NetBeans UML plugin has been discontinued, as [per a discussion on the NetBeans forums](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic19405.html). This was a great, free tool with nice model->code and code->model generation.

There are a number of other UML NetBeans plugins out there. However, I've never used any of them. Any suggestions?

Comment: I wish there were a way to flag an offensive flag as offensive.

Comment: You could generate Class diagram with Netbeans 6.8. No usecase diagram is possible from java code only class or sequence diagram. Netbeans 7.0 does not support UML.

Comment: Perhaps: https://netbeans.org/projects/uml/downloads

Answer (score 14):

I had also a problem with installing UML for my NetBeans 6.8. Most of solutions proposed in the Web doesn't seem to work. Today I have finally find how to install UML plugin on NetBeans 6.8.

**Step by step explanation of the process of installation of the plugin:**

1. Go to
   http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/netbeans/updates/6.7.1/uc/final/beta/modules/uml6/
   and download all .nbm files from there.
2. Open NetBeans and go to Tools->Plugins->Downloaded
3. Click on Add plugins… button
4. Select all .nbm files you have downloaded from the source mentioned above.
5. Follow step by step wizard of NetBeans to install plugins

Hope that helps you also. As for me I am enjoying UML in NetBeans starting from today. 
***Good luck.***

Comment: I Downloaded the file given in the above mentioned URL but the downloaded zip doesn't contains *.nbm file which is required.

Comment: Does it work for Netbeans 7.2 also? I followed the above procedure, then when I restart the Netbean IDE , it stuck at loading modules. Please suggest.

Comment: you could just add catalog.xml.gz to Netbeans, click 'Tools' -> 'Plugins' -> 'Settings' -> and add the following url as a Update Center http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/netbeans/updates/6.7.1/uc/final/beta/catalog.xml.gz Then just click 'Available Plugins' tab and click 'Reload Catalog' you now should see 'UML' listed as plugin to install

Answer (score 4):

So after reading a bunch of the internet, the team responsible for the NeatBeans UML plugin is working on it, but it isn't done yet. They have decided to start over because the old code is unsustainable, which is why it doesn't work with 7.x.

Nevertheless, as this post points out, people want UML Diagrams, so below is a link to my blog, which provides a way of getting UML Diagrams of your classes from NetBeans 7.x.

http://imagine.kicbak.com/blog/?p=58

You cannot generate code from diagrams with my solution, but you CAN generate UML Diagrams in your JavaDocs from your classes in your project. This is a Code -> Model solution only. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Check this :

- [Generating UML From the NetBeans IDE](http://blogs.oracle.com/JavaFundamentals/entry/generating_uml_from_the_netbeans)
- [SDE for NetBeans (CE) for Windows 6.0](http://sde-for-netbeans-ce-for-windows.visual-paradigm-international-ltd.qarchive.org/)

---

If you switch over to Eclipse, there are plenty of them.

- [Recommended Eclipse plugins to generate UML from Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786/recommended-eclipse-plugins-to-generate-uml-from-java-code)
- [Good free UML tool for Java/Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390438/good-free-uml-tool-for-java-eclipse)
- [UML editor for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287114/uml-editor-for-java)

Answer (score 1):

The bundled UML plugin was removed from 7.0 and is undergoing a rewrite as [EidosUML](http://wiki.netbeans.org/EidosUML). The community edition of Visual Paradigm's [Smart Development Environment](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/download/sdenb.jsp?edition=ce) works with Netbeans 7.0 afaik

Comment: Just an FYI: I've used Visual Paradigm's tools before and from my experience whenever you want to do some kind of generation like the one needed above, they want you to purchase their pro version.