# The UML plugin for Netbeans IDE is generating no results just empty folders!

Tags: java, netbeans, uml, netbeans-6.9, netbeans-plugins

Please, When i am trying to reverse engineering my project (from .java to UML) under netbeans, I am receiving just a set of empty folders. Any ideas about what possibly the problem can be?

I am running Netbeans IDE 6.9.1. The UML was supported in the previous version, though it is possible to install it manually on the new version too.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans 6.9 doesn't work with UML diagrams. You need to switch back to the 6.5 version or to Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

go back to 6.8, UML diagrams still visible. Trick: Just open project and then "NEW diagram", "OLD diagrams" will be recovered!!!.

Comment: Same with NetBeans 7.3. [Plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983257/recommended-netbeans-uml-plugins/2912545#2912545) generates empty nodes and datastructures. Restarting NetBeans causes everything to become invisible. Creating a diagram makes what was visible before become visible again. However, none of the models have any data visibly associated with them; a report generated from such a UML project includes lots of data, that is not visible in the project, but is supposed to be.

Wow, it'd be really good to work with UML from NetBeans. Any suggestions? :/