# How to generate UML diagrams from Java?

Tags: java, netbeans, uml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recommended NetBeans UML plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983257/recommended-netbeans-uml-plugins)

How can I generate Use Case and Class diagrams from Java code?

I'm using NetBeans 7.0.