# UML Reverse Engineering in Netbeans Broken

Tags: java, netbeans, uml, reverse-engineering, netbeans-7

**My Goal:** I want to make a UML diagram out of my java project in Netbeans. I don't really care how it's done particularly, as long as it looks good.

I saw [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2912545/971592) on Stack Overflow about how to reverse engineer a UML diagram based on Java Code in Netbeans. I attempted the solution and I think most of it works except a few problems which make the solution worthless.

Basically, what I'm experiencing is I will implement the step-by-step instructions in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2912545/971592) to install the UML plugin, and then right click on the project BONotifier (see below) and click "Reverse Engineer" and use it as the source for the UMLProject1 (see below).

[image: Broken UML modeler]

However, when I open UMLProject1, nothing appears under the model (as you can see in the image above), there should be over 20 classes in there... What could be wrong? Thanks!

Oh, and the output of the Reverse Engineering Log can be found in [this pastie](http://beta.pastie.org/private/7nlmzaanjouveqx70zgxw). I think it may have to do with the fact that this plugin is a little older and the project is running jdk 1.7. I tried it on a 1.6 project and experienced the same problems.

I'm totally open to an alternative solution. I've tried eclipse solutions and I'm not happy with them. I'd prefer a Netbeans solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [no plan to support UML in Netbeans](http://wiki.netbeans.org/UMLSupport) past version 7. It appears something happened in the revisions that broke UML support in the OP's version of Netbeans. Also, the original plugin does not support JDK version 1.7, so you need to use version 1.6 and below. So [download Netbeans 6.7.1](http://netbeans.org/downloads/6.7.1/index.html) and it'll work fine.