# Need UML reverse engineering tool for Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml

I need to maintain some project in Java, but it is very big. I need some plugin for Eclipse or program alone which can generate UML from Java project. Is there something what can help me ?

Answer (score 12):

[Visual Paradigm for UML](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/download/vpuml.jsp)

Tools --> Instant Reverse --> Java --> Specify your sources and you are done.

This is a commercial application with lots of stuff, but for what you need to do, you are fine with the evaluation key.

EDIT: Also have a look at this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udfjekpEDak)

Answer (score 8):

This has been asked before.. please find it at

[How to generate UML diagrams (especially sequence diagrams) from Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786/recommended-eclipse-plugins-to-generate-uml-from-java-code)

Comment: Link you have provided is broken. Please update your answer.

Comment: Link seems to work ok and lists lots of good options.

Comment: Also check out my http://www.gituml.com which generates UML diagrams from Java & Python code in GitHub repositories. Diagrams automatically update when you push code using git.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend [Architexa](http://www.architexa.com) for its great class digram generation. Instead of generating every classes in a huge class diagram, Arhitexa allows you to selectively display the relevant classes in the diagram.

Comment: Architexa does not work any any remotely recent version of Eclipse.  The last version that works is 4.2 and 4.8 was just released.

Answer (score 5):

Most UML tools can import Java code.  Last time I used JUDE Community edition it could do it, but they've split it into community and paid editions.  I'm not sure if the free one does anymore.  Sparx Enterprise Architect can import Java as well.

Comment: +1 because Enterprise Architect is a great UML tool (great diagramming tool in general).

Answer (score 4):

[Umbrello](http://uml.sourceforge.net/) supports Java code import, and it is open source, so will cost you nothing to try.

You might also give [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)(with [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/)) a go; it will generate UML 'style' class diagrams and is a great code navigation tool for unfamiliar code-bases.  Not truly a UML tool though, but might suit your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest [euml2](http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/) as an eclipse pluggin.
It has a free version and it is quite good!

Comment: eUML will add tags in your code and will entirely rewrite your code in order to add model annotation in the code. The model is said to be corrupt and if you need advanced features then you have to pay over $1600 !! To absolutely avoid

Comment: @user294000:Well it adds meta-data in comments e.g. 
`/*** @uml.property  name="variableName"* @uml.associationEnd */` but that did not create a problem for me. I have used it for class diagrams and package diagrams and was ok. If you have more advanced usage experience and you saw bugs, well thank you for telling me to keep in mind

Comment: @user294000:Also it has a free version for the basic stuff. The other suggestions are very good but have only trial versions.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/) which supports full reverse and forward engineering including for Java.  Automatic Documentation generation as Word, PDF or website.

Answer (score 0):

Free [Class Visualizer](http://www.class-visualizer.net/) does exactly that - you load compiled Java code and, as a result, receive class diagrams allowing you to navigate through relations.
It supports parametrized types, annotations and discovers all sort of outbound and inbound relations (including dependencies).