# Tools which can draw a project's architecture? 

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, uml

I have one product which is developed in J2EE, the technology that I used as Java, JSF, and for the back end I used AS400 (DB2 database).  I am using eclipse IDE.  Are there any tools which can help me draw the flow of my product, UML diagrams and the class diagrams.

Comment: If you check questions in the proper tags, you'll find lot of similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse+uml

Comment: You mentioned UML diagrams in your question, but comment on an answer that you don't want a UML diagram you want something to draw the architecture.  What do you mean by architecture?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recommended Eclipse plugins to generate UML from Java code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786/recommended-eclipse-plugins-to-generate-uml-from-java-code)

Comment: you cannot get a good architecture documentation automatically, architecture is too high level to decide automatically what is important what is not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UML tool that I like is [plantuml](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/) It lets you write a text description of a diagram, so you have a lot of flexibility in what you include or exclude. There are plugins for everything from Eclipse to Microsoft Word and even an online servlet. There are tools to reverse engineer classes and you can also embed diagrams into javadoc if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

This is good one. It can draw class, activity,sequence and Usecase diagrams.
http://amateras.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/fswiki_en/wiki.cgi?page=AmaterasUML

Comment: i know the tools which can draw UML but i want the tool from which i can opne my project and the it will automatically draw the architecture

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Visual Paradigm SDE for Eclipse

Link: http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/sde/ec/

you can capture requirements, design databases, generate code, implement software and generate reports. SDE supports UML, entity relationship diagram, BPMN and SysML.

Also there are different versions a good version is the Comunity one which is for free..!

Answer (score 0):

[StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/) is a very good option. It is free and supports most of UML2. This is not being maintained but it is rock solid for what you need.

1. Use [interaction diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_diagram#Interaction_diagrams) to document high level flow of your product
2. Use [class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram)/[object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_diagram) diagrams to provide static view
3. Use [activity diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram) to document workflow/algorithms

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an UML model from your database.

You can use Dali without EclipseUML but database annotations would be lost during the UML reverse engineering if not using Omondo.