# Create class diagram for project documentation

Tags: eclipse, class-diagram

---

What **tool/plugin** should i use to ***create a class diagram*** for my Java Project in Eclipse?

Thanks!

---

Comment: I didn't voted here, but it would be better to ask this [here](programmers.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @daemon_x: because...? real programmers write machine code, not diagrams?

Comment: it is needed for my documentation. i am required to submit my project with this diagram..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ObjectAid](http://www.objectaid.com/class-diagram) is a very useful plugin.. It works well.. :)

Answer (score 2):

See here

[How to generate UML diagrams (especially sequence diagrams) from Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786/recommended-eclipse-plugins-to-generate-uml-from-java-code)

eUML seems easy and free

Answer (score 0):

As a free but external tool I would recommend UMLet.