# Any free reliable activity diagram tools for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, uml, activity-diagram

I always hear Eclipse developers talking about how great Eclipse is because it has plugins for everything for free...

But I have been looking for any free reliable UML tools with no success.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

> UML2 is an EMF-based implementation of
>   the Unified Modeling Language (UML)
>   2.x OMG metamodel for the Eclipse platform.

You can find more info on the UML2 project at http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=uml2

I'm sure there are others too. I have to admit, I tried a few Eclipse-based UML modelling tools a couple of years ago when I had need of UML. I ended up using a separate free UML modelling tool as the Eclipse based options were very complex and seemed a bit unreliable, but things might be better now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out with [Jupe](http://jupe.binaervarianz.de/)

Also see

- [Recommended Eclipse plugins to generate UML from Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786/recommended-eclipse-plugins-to-generate-uml-from-java-code)
- [Good free UML tool for Java/Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390438/good-free-uml-tool-for-java-eclipse/395528#395528)
- [Eclipse UML plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988384/eclipse-uml-plugin)