# Tools for visualizing, understanding how your classes relate to one another

Tags: java, object-oriented-analysis

At times I find myself struggling to navigate the object landscape of a large, legacy system having 100+ classes.

This seems like a fairly common challenge.

I'm just curious if there are any highly recommended tools out there that compile your source code and produce some kind of visualization of how your objects relate to one another.

Thanks.

Comment: Checkout this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786/recommended-eclipse-plugins-to-generate-uml-from-java-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many good reverse engineering tools are available. Some are commercialy availbale like Rational Rose, Enterprise Architect and visual paradigm. In Open source I like [Star UML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/), [Argo UML](http://argouml.tigris.org/). [Class dependency analyzer](http://www.dependency-analyzer.org/) is also good one.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [CDA](http://www.dependency-analyzer.org/) and their quick start [guide](http://www.dependency-analyzer.org/#QuickStart).

Answer (score 1):

You can generate an UML Class Diagram using reverse engineering with tools like [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/).