# Plugin for RAD to generate UML from Java code

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recommended Eclipse plugins to generate UML from Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786/recommended-eclipse-plugins-to-generate-uml-from-java-code)

I am using RAD 8. Here is its eclipse version information.

Eclipse RCP
Version: 3.6.2

Is there any plugin that can draw uml class diagram from Java source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several. Have a look at [Topcased](http://www.topcased.org/index.php?idd_projet_pere=24) for example.

Also, look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786/recommended-eclipse-plugins-to-generate-uml-from-java-code)

Comment: I placed this plugin in RAD plugin directory. How to use it?

Comment: I suggest you start by downloading the standalone RCP version of Topcased and try that out. It will save you the hassle of handling dependencies and other things. As for how to use it, look at the documentation http://www.topcased.org/index.php?documentsSynthesis=y&Itemid=59