# What is the best Eclispe UML plugin for drawing diagrams only?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recommended Eclipse plugins to generate UML from Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786/recommended-eclipse-plugins-to-generate-uml-from-java-code)

I think my title says everything. I want to use a Eclipse plugin to draw UML diagrams.

I use Eclipse for R programming so I don't need any UML with java support. In case the best

drawing one supports java I would not mind either.

Cheers

Comment: This is such a common question its even in the faq  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-plugin+uml?sort=faq&pagesize=15

Answer (score 0):

I always kinda liked the [eUML 2 by Soyatec](http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/). You didn't require that, but it has quite nice support for Java. I used it in several projects - it has some drawbacks, but at the end I would recommend it anyway.

Comment: But it requires to create a Java project which is not what I want :) I want to create a new UML diagram by right click -> new file -> other and can be put in any kind of project

Answer (score 0):

[Papyrus](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/papyrus/) is a good tool with basic documentation for different diagrams.

Comment: Is this the successor of the UML2Tools plugin for Eclipse? UML2Tools seems not to be developed further...