# Plugin for UML in Eclipse

Tags: uml

Please advise me for plugin that I can install in my ecliipse(indigo) for generating uml and sequence diagrams from existing code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recommended Eclipse plugins to generate UML from Java code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786/recommended-eclipse-plugins-to-generate-uml-from-java-code)

Answer (score 0):

My personal favorite is http://objectaid.com/

It quickly visualizes java class as UML, there is also commercial tools for sequence diagrams

Answer (score -1):

The best UML for Java with Eclipse Indigo is EclipseUML Omondo but not free and very expensive.

You don't today have any other tool for indigo which can do this job. Some other tools say they can do it but I have never been able to install them or to successfully reverse a simple method into a sequence diagram !!

Comment: It is too strong statement, that only 1 commercial tool can do the job.

Comment: Why ? The omondo team worked 7 years to improve the sequence diagram reverse engineering. Very heavy project but it was worth waiting !!