# Reading UML Model in Eclipse Indigo?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a newbie in Eclipse Indigo.
Actually, my task is to Develop a PLUGIN which will **READ THE UML MODELS** through the ECLIPSE INDIGO. i.e., When i run that plugin **IT SHOULD READ EVERY THING IN THAT UML MODEL, such as CLASSES, METHODS** etc.,
So can i get any guidelines for this ?? 
May i get any kind of sample coding for this ??

### Thanks

Sriram R.

Comment: UML diagrams are typically stored in a text format, mostly XML. You can try to parse this XML file. What format do you want to use? Do you have a name or a sample file?

Comment: There's no need for caps or bolding to make your point.  And no, this isn't a good site for sample code.

Answer (score 0):

There are likely to be several existing eclipse plug-ins that will do what you're asking, so I would suggest looking at these before committing to create your own plugin. 
If you are set on making your own plugin, then the solution will depend on the format of the UML files you need to parse. Some of the UML plug-ins use EMF (Eclipse Modelling Framework), in which case you would want to base your plugin on EMF. Others use XML, in which case you have many options including straight forward parsing or using XML object frameworks like XMLBeans or JAXB. 
Sorry I can't be more specific but your question is rather vague.

Answer (score 0):

Very unclear what you are looking for. You should start by [searching this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=eclipse%20uml) for more information, there are plenty of Eclipse plugins that handles UML, see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786/recommended-eclipse-plugins-to-generate-uml-from-java-code%20that%20hand). Then when you have evaluated the alternatives, find what you need that the existing plugins dont do.