# Procedure to draw the hierarchy of classes in Java?

Tags: java, uml

Actually I am totally confused with the number of classes and interfaces in Java, for easily understanding do we have any way of representing the classes in diagrams format? As I have referred to API's of java. It only shows classes with interfaces but not clearly present the relationship between different classes and interfaces.

Comment: What, like a UML diagram?  What kinds of relationships?  There are plugins for eclipse that will auto-generate these sorts of things...

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to generate a UML diagram of the Java language itself?

Comment: This is discussed in details in [Recommended Eclipse plugins to generate UML from Java code][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786/recommended-eclipse-plugins-to-generate-uml-from-java-code

Answer (score 0):

The linked discussion on Recommended Eclipse plugins is good, but I would also add one more that I didn't see included. I've used [UML Graph](http://www.umlgraph.org/) for this purpose. It generates UML diagrams based on your code an inserts them into the JavaDoc.