# Generating flow diagram in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any plugin which can be installed in Eclipse that will generate the flow diagram if we pass our java code to it? Suppose I have code and I want a flow diagram to be generated that will help me to visualize.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786/recommended-eclipse-plugins-to-generate-uml-from-java-code) similar and well answered question on SO

Answer (score 2):

Have try of StarUML where I reverse engineered Java code to generate Class Diagrams and package diagrams.

It will help us to build Sequence Diagram which may server your pupose.

I feel it is more efficient than trying an Eclipse Plugin.

I have not tried this

http://www.vogella.com/articles/UML/article.html#install

whether it will reverse engineer the java code