# Reverse Engineering Code in UML using ecplise

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I generate the UML Class diagram using eclipse. Is there any plugin in the market which will enable me to generate the class diagram.

Comment: Do you have the source code or just the .class files?

Comment: I do have source code

Comment: Did you try googling "uml eclipse"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recommended Eclipse plugins to generate UML from Java code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786/recommended-eclipse-plugins-to-generate-uml-from-java-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you talking about compiled classes you don't have the sourcecode to?

did you try Apollo?

http://www.gentleware.com/apollo.html

Comment: then you shoudl definitely check out apollo. it used to be a bit heavy, and have not used it in a while, but you can try it for free anyway, i think ...