# Create UML and generate code in Eclipse 4.2

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml, eclipse-juno

I want to create a UML and then generate code from that UML in Eclipse 4.2 (Juno). Can anyone suggest any free plugin to do the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recommended Eclipse plugins to generate UML from Java code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786/recommended-eclipse-plugins-to-generate-uml-from-java-code)

Comment: @Fredrik for me it is not the same here he wants to generate code (maybe java) from UML models, in your link the asked question is to generate UML model from Java...

Comment: @Gupta takes a look at http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/m2t/ and http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=uml2

Comment: try this : http://lowcoupling.com/post/47347056110/models-to-text-transformations-with-mofm2t-and-acceleo