# Uml tool from Java source code

Tags: java, uml, reverse-engineering

I am using an open source java framework that includes several jar packages. I would like to get to know the architecture of the framework so I am looking for a free tool that does reverse engineering.

Particularly I m looking for a tool to generate Uml diagrams (or just the class hierarchy and maybe the dependencies among packages) from the Java source code.

Anybody knows such a free tool?

Comment: I'm using `UMLet` for yearz, and it's perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool I used was [ObjectAid](http://www.objectaid.com/) and I found it as a good tool.

Comment: I use ObjectAid too. It's a nice tool altough the generated Class Diagramm isn't very fancy. Visual Paradigm looks more posh ;).

Answer (score 1):

if you are workiing with netbeans: http://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpumluserguide/2381/2384/66565_reverseengin.html

this another product free-trial 30 days: 
[altova](http://www.altova.com/umodel/uml-reverse-engineering.html)

eclipse : [eclipse UML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786/recommended-eclipse-plugins-to-generate-uml-from-java-code)

Comment: Visual Paradigm is available for Eclipse too :).

Answer (score 1):

[Modelio](http://www.modelio.org/) with this Java module are able to do so...