# Trying to find an extension for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, bluej

Is there and extension I can get for eclipse which has a similar layout to Bluej using colours   for seperate blocks of code i.e. Class, Methods, If Statements etc.

Comment: Yes there it is. A good one actually. But not for free.

Comment: Thanks, do you know of a link for this extension? or the name?.

Comment: Looking for it right now, I forgot the name on the damn thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find the paid plugin I was talking about in the comments, but instead I found similar StackOverflow questions:

- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786/recommended-eclipse-plugins-to-generate-uml-from-java-code)
- [And here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988384/eclipse-uml-plugin)
- [Also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390438/good-free-uml-tool-for-java-eclipse/395528#395528)

Although I don't know of any actual plugins that create and compile visual class blocks, it would be a better practice (e.g. for a beginner) to actually write code, then view the UML representation of what he wrote, instead of working directly with those blocks. But that's my humble opinion.

Cheers.