# How to create UML in Android Studio?

Tags: java, eclipse, android-studio, uml, android-studio-3.0

The UML generators found on other answers in StackOverflow are mostly outdated and do not work with Android Studio anymore. How do you create a UML in Android Studio?

Answer (score 2):

Since the newest version of Android Studio doesn't work with the old UML generators, I do not believe it is currently possible to create a UML in Android Studio. However, there is an easy workaround.
Using the Eclipse IDE UML generator (more information about that here: [How to generate UML diagrams (especially sequence diagrams) from Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786/how-to-generate-uml-diagrams-especially-sequence-diagrams-from-java-code) ) one can simply copy and paste all the classes from Android Studio into a new Eclipse project. Ignoring the errors, create a UML as you usually do in Eclipse (right click on project folder --> Click New --> Other --> ObjectAid UML Diagram folder --> ObjectAid Class Diagram ) Drag all of the classes (with the red errors) into the UML window and a UML will be created. Save the UML and then you can delete the new Project since it won't work in Eclipse.