# generate uml from existing source eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, uml

Just a quick question. I have a Spring boot crud application and need to generate a class diagram for it. Is that posible to generate one using eclipse. I tryed to research this topic but nothin found. Some are not maintained some simply don't work. I use latest 2021-09 eclipse for Java Enterprice.
UPDATE: I tryed to use plant uml. It generates somethin, but one by one can I generate the diagram just in once for whole project. Like it is done in Visual Studio for example?

Comment: Finaly I solved the problem with InteliJ Idea. Somethin similar for eclipse I could not find. So please do not minus me and let this question be open for a while...

Answer (score 1):

visit [How to generate UML diagrams (especially sequence diagrams) from Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786/how-to-generate-uml-diagrams-especially-sequence-diagrams-from-java-code)

Take a look at this one here (Your question is already answered)

Comment: I tryed this. Basicly I am there now. Very first module can help if it was a life.